# React How to make an <a> tag always treat the href value as an absolute path

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In React I'm trying to have an  tag that that redirect the user to dynamically set value like this:

```
<a href={url} >{url}</a>
```

The problem is that the 'url' can have 'https' or not. for example if the value of url is : com.com then the application treat the 'url' value as relative and append the value to localhost : localhost:3000/path/com.com

How Can I make sure the value given to  is treated like absolute value.

Comment: try to use an eslint regex for this purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-regex

Comment: Would the [JavaScript URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) be of use to you?

Comment: @AndrewMorton URL does not accept url as 'com.com'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple function that checks if the URL starts with "http/https", and if not just add it to the URL, something like that:

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-glitter-pr5gw?file=/src/App.js:264-268

Comment: I was trying not to do it this way but I guess there is no standard way to do it. Thanks.